# CSS keyframe animation - position: how to place a circle exactly on top of the cone?

Tags: css, position, css-animations

I am working on CSS keyframe animation and trying to move a circle on top of a cone, which will look like an ice-cream.

I use the absolute position but unfortunately it does not work for me. I try to use % as I would like the page to be more responsive.

Many thanks.

edited: added HTML

```
        <div id="flavour-con">
          <div id="orange" class="flavour"><p>orange</p></div>
          <div id="mango" class="flavour"><p>mango</p></div>
          <div id="strawberry" class="flavour"><p>strawberry</p</div>
          <div id="blueberry" class="flavour"><p>blueberry</p></div>
          <div id="cookies" class="flavour"><p>cookies</p></div>
          <div id="mint" class="flavour"><p>mint</p></div>
        </div>

      <div id="cone"></div>
```

CSS for the circle:

```
.flavour{
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 1s;
  background-color: orange;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  left: 10%;
}

.flavourselected{
  animation: flavourSelected 1s 1 ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes flavourSelected {
  100%{
    top: calc(90% - 60px); 
    left: calc(50% + 20px); 
    transform: scale(3);
  }
}
```

CSS for the cone:

```
#cone {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 60px solid transparent;
  border-right: 60px solid transparent;
  border-top: 120px solid lightsalmon;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

I tried to adjust the top and left numbers for many times but the circle did not land on the cone perfectly.

Comment: Please add your html code.

Comment: CSS without any HTML it is supposed to apply to, tells us rather little. Please present a proper [mre] when asking a question like this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your original keyframe animation:

```
@keyframes flavourSelected {
  100%{
    top: calc(90% - 50px); 
    left: calc(50% + 40px); 
    transform: scale(3);
  }
}
```

With these adjustments, the circle should now land perfectly on the cone.

Comment: Should have added a working example instead.